# IF with or statement php

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi can someone tell me how I would change this...

```
if($values['CountryName']="England");
```

to include an or statement, ie if = "England" or "Scotland" or "Wales";

Thanks

Ok so please just humour me, would it be...
if($values['CountryName']=="England" || $values['CountryName']=="Wales" || $values['CountryName']=="Scotland" )

{`enter code here`

Comment: Also note that `=` is the assignment operator, and `==` for comparisons.

Comment: if($values['CountryName']=="England" OR $values['CountryName']=="Scotland" OR  $values['CountryName']=="Wales");